# Justify upgrade to C++11/14 from c++98 to my management

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I work on a mixed codebase (Java/C++) of 1M-2M lines of code and we are upgrading our development environment to RHEL 7.3 and gcc from 4.5 to 4.8.5 which does give some (experimental) support for C++11.

The C++ code has been around for a few years and you would be hard pushed to find any use of STL containers as most of the current coders believe that c-style arrays and raw pointers are the most efficient way to code [we do a lot of signal processing stuff in the Defence domain]. We use a bit of Boost and ACE for threading/networking/timers/filesystem.

I need a few good reasons to present to management to persuade them that upgrading gcc to 6.1/2/3 would be beneficial. The most compelling argument would revolve around performance but given the heavy usage of c-style arrays and raw pointers I'm not sure that upgrading helps.

I am aware of the of the new language features such as lambdas, auto, threading, uniform initialization, smart pointers but don't know how to 'sell' these features. In fact, I think the new features might be seen as more of a hindrance as any usage of them would require the current developers to understand their usage.

There doesn't seem to be any reluctance to upgrade RHEL 7.3 to use Java 8 on the grounds that it contains the latest 'security patches' but upgrading C++ meets more resistance!

Comment: You're now upgrading from a 10-year-old compiler to an 8-year-old compiler? :-) To get experimental support for a revision of the Standard that's outdated by two generations?

Comment: It will become increasingly difficult to recruit competent programmers who are willing to code in C++98/03.

Comment: I think this belongs on [softwareengineering.se]

Comment: @KerrekSB I guess it is because RHEL :-)

Comment: You could compile some parts of your codebase with the new GCC and profile it, and if there is a performance boost, you can present that as an arguement. Also, the new GCC may find someing interesting with `-Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: Can you get them to give you a VM or two and get a CI server which builds the code the current way and against a newer compile and point out the build times? And put up a sutiable xkcd poster about compiling? https://xkcd.com/303/

Comment: The problem is probably not C++ in itself but the need to ship/build a compatible compiler. If you're using a compiler bundled with RHEL you'll probably have support for it. If you build your own gcc you probably don't. You'll need manpower to work on the compiler.

Comment: @doctorlove, Build time is not an issue to the managment. ;) Arguments for the managament can be: Hard to find good developers, increasing maintenance costs, expiration of (API) support, OS support, risc of outdated hardware and associated with this the costs of running and maintaining it. Increasing amount of time to get new staff to be productive. Depending on your business there may also be security issues.

Comment: just show them listings of versions of test functions written in C style and modern c++ style with asm output of both. If they can't understand this argument, they neither care about performance, nor competent to manage

Comment: @KerrekSB RHEL 7.3 is actually the latest release which is a major step up for us as previously we used Centos 5.4!

Comment: Ask them if they use Win98 too. If your management need more convincing, ask for a reference instead.